# Function instantiation has undefined input shape at index: 92 in the outer inference context. | Tensorwflow 2.0

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

"Function instantiation has undefined input shape at index: 92 in the outer inference context."

I am getting this warning for some reason. Could give me any hint where to look to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

Solved it, just removed @tf.function from one function,  not sure why but it helped.

Comment: This is not a solution